# Apply an extended ACL on Cisco 7609 SIP-400

Tags: cisco, troubleshooting, acl, pbr

Good morning,

I have configured a pbr to apply it to a virtual-template 
here is my route-map definition :

```
route-map to_virtual_template permit 10

 match ip address 101

 set ip next-hop X.X.X.1
```

Access-List is defined as:

```
access-list 101 permit ip any any
```

And I apply here to the Virtual-Template interface:

```
interface Virtual-Template1
 description Template_1
 ip policy route-map to_virtual_template
```

The pbr is not being applied and i wonder if had to be with the SIP-400 card, if ACLs are only allowed on access subinterfaces... Or I have to take something more into account?

The SUP is a SUP7203BXL and IOS 12.2(33) SRE.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively you can answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [documentation on Cisco Support Forums](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10599211/pppoe-7600), PBR isn't supported on Virtual-Template interfaces (at least with SIP-400):

> Yasir Ashfaque 4 years ago
>
> Well 2*Gbe must work, you must confirm it from CISCO TAC, beside that i dont see any issue, make sure you will use IOS greater than 12.2SRC and note it that policy-routing doesnt work on virtual-access interface. beside that it works gr8

Comment: So is it possible to route some of the clients traffic (virtual-access interfaces) somehow ?  I imagine that this is something related to the SIP-400 card because this configuration works on 7200 NPE-Ge...

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do with the client's traffic... can you be more specific?  Are you trying to treat some clients differently than others?  If so, you may need to terminate them on distinct Virtual-Templates (either in a vrf - if that works), or on separate routers

Comment: Hi Mike, that pbr is just to force the traffic between clients to pass through a traffic shaper...

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle this... I need to research whether SIP-400 has native traffic-shaping abilities on PPPoE traffic... seems like it should

Comment: It would be wonderfull! I am also looking at the SIP-400 doc.

Comment: If i had a 15 IOS Version i think this config would be possible